# Expose Container Port to specific host IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am able to forward a container port to the global host IP when running:

```
docker run -p IP:5000:5000 container_name
```

or in docker-compose:

```
ports:
- "5000:5000"`
```

However, the following opens the hosts' port to all external IP addresses. How can I make the port accessible to one host A with IP address X, and no other IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines can restrict access to an opened port on a docker container:

```
iptables -I DOCKER ! -s IP_ADDRESS -j DROP
```

Reference:

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302824/iptables-allow-docker-port-forwarding-only-for-specific-ip-address

Docker IP Table Manipulation:

> https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as a configuration option. You can create a script that will serve as your **ENTRYPOINT** and as part of that script set inbound rules before running your app.

Example flow inside of your custom Entrypoint script:

1. Receive a ENV variable the IP that you want to allow to use your app.
2. Use the ENV variable to configure your inbound rules (maybe using iptables)
3. Run your app

By doing this, all the connections/requests from undesired IPs will be dropped.

You can find a very good sample here: https://dev.to/andre/docker-restricting-in--and-outbound-network-traffic-67p

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation: when specifying format you can also mention to which IP address you want to bind. (Default is to bind with all the IP-Address-0.0.0.0)

```
EXPOSE (incoming ports)
The following run command options work with container networking:

--expose=[]: Expose a port or a range of ports inside the container.
             These are additional to those exposed by the `EXPOSE` instruction
-P         : Publish all exposed ports to the host interfaces
-p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host
               format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort
               Both hostPort and containerPort can be specified as a
               range of ports. When specifying ranges for both, the
               number of container ports in the range must match the
               number of host ports in the range, for example:
                   -p 1234-1236:1234-1236/tcp

               When specifying a range for hostPort only, the
               containerPort must not be a range.  In this case the
               container port is published somewhere within the
               specified hostPort range. (e.g., `-p 1234-1236:1234/tcp`)

               (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)

--link=""  : Add link to another container (<name or id>:alias or <name or id>)
```

Reference : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: I think I misunderstood your query.
You want to accept requests coming from one specific machine A (as IP-Address) only.